# How does Watson solve Geography problems?

Tags: algorithm

In spite of [losing to humans on the geography question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lI-M7O_bRNg&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_383798#t=3m11s), Watson still won Jeopardy.

The explanations regarding this incorrect answer seem a bit lame to me (at 3:40 in the video).

[image: watson]

With a logo like this, I would expect Watson to perform better at finding a city based on airport attributes.
Does anyone have any links describing how [Watson](http://www-943.ibm.com/innovation/us/watson/watson-for-a-smarter-planet/watson-schematic.html) performs geospatial reasoning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Smarter Planet had a [great blog entry](http://asmarterplanet.com/blog/2011/02/watson-on-jeopardy-day-two-the-confusion-over-an-airport-clue.html) on why Watson got the answer wrong.

Also, Bruce Upbin wrote specifically about Watson [performing a spatial operation](http://blogs.forbes.com/bruceupbin/2011/02/14/ibms-watson-computer-will-win/):

> There are many reasons Watson is good
>   at Jeopardy!. It has something like a
>   million pages of documents and a
>   geospatial database in its memory. It
>   can run the board on categories like
>   “Northernmost Capital Cities,” in
>   which you’re given a trio of capital
>   cities and have to name the
>   northernmost one. Watson doesn’t
>   really “get” that the category is
>   looking for geographical information
>   off the bat. That isn’t a simple
>   assumption to deduce from the category
>   syntax, but it catches on quickly that
>   all it has to do is compare the
>   latitude of each city in the trio and
>   give the one with the highest number.
>   It buzzes in correctly on Stockholm,
>   Bogota, Pyongyang, Algiers and
>   Kathmandu. A.J. and I knew some of
>   these, but that’s when Watson’s other
>   superior trait kicks in; the machine
>   is lightning-fast at buzzing in
>   answers.

Comment: Thanks seth, I wonder how much spatial data they fed Watson.

Comment: @Kirk - All of it probably!  It'd be awesome if those guys showed up at DevSummit.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this blog post on reddit:  [IBM Watson Research Team Answers Your Questions](http://blog.reddit.com/2011/02/ibm-watson-research-team-answers-your.html) Nothing specific to geography but there is a general description of how Watson arrives at an answer to questions.

Comment: I'm surprised there's nothing specific to geography.  I think "where can I drill for oil and make a profit?" would be a natural question.

Comment: The next question should be "Where is Osama Bin Laden?" so the United States can return to "normal". :-)